# Mod_rewrite works on local, not on remote, version?

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I have this site. Let's call it htp://www.mysite.com

I have a rewrite rule to change `htp://www.mysite.com/?q=words%20etc/0/10` into `http://www.mysite.com/words%20etc/0/10` (or `http://www.mysite.com//0/10` or `http://www.mysite.com/0/10`)

```
.htaccess:ErrorDocument 404 htp://www.mysite.com/404.html
options +FollowSymlinks
rewriteEngine on
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
rewriteRule ^/?([^/]+?)?/?([0-9]+?)/([0-9]+?)$ index.php/%{THE_REQUEST} [NC]
```

Now, this works on my local apache 2.2.11 server, no errors. However on my host's apache 1.3.41 server, I get the following error:

```
[Sat Mar 5 21:42:14 2011] [alert] [client [ip]] /home/_/public_html/mysite.com/.htaccess: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^/?([^/]+?)?/?([0-9]+?)/([0-9]+?)$'\n
```

I imagine it's something quirky about the apache version as other sites on this host use mod_rewrite without a hitch.

I've tried removing the `+followSymlinks` line, even the rewrite engine line. I haven't tried removing the conditions cause I don't think I should have to, I'm probably wrong.

Comment: it probably is to do with the v1.3 apache server -- it does have significant differences to v2; it's tripped me up a number of times with mod_rewrite in the past. But really, your remote host should have upgraded by now -- Apache 1.3 was declared end of life over a year ago. It isn't as if v2 is new an untested.

Comment: I'd start with the old 1.3-era mod_rewrite docs: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule

Answer (score 0):

Answer here: http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/4277342.htm

I'm using ? wrong mostly. Will post solution when it works.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
options +FollowSymlinks
rewriteEngine on
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
rewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index\.php
rewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?q=$1&s=$2&p=$3 [NC]
rewriteRule ^/?([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$ index.php?q=&s=$1&p=$2 [NC]
```

fixeddddd.